# RFI noise impact on ADC

Tags: rf, circuit-design, analog, electromagnetism, emc

I am trying to debug the issue where RFI noise is increasing the ADC's analog input values when a Walkie-Talkie is switched on (transmitter mode, 470MHz) nearby.

[image: Input circuit diagram with interferer]

What could be the quick tips to mitigate the RFI noise issue on this ADC as shown in image?

1. Replacing R4 from zero ohm to ferrite bead to provide isolation between AGND and DGND?
2. Increasing value of R2 and R1 to reduce current in the trace to weaken the magnetic field around trace and hence magnetic coupling for RF signals?
3. Increasing the order of filter after buffer U1 to have steep attenuation for noise?

kindly provide your valuable suggestions and also give your thoughts on above listed quick tips.

Thanks

Comment: Is the radiation applied to the circuit overall? What does the layout look like? Or is it within a metallic enclosure, in which case, how is the circuit connected to it?

Comment: @TimWilliams , The PCB is in metallic inclosure . radiation is applied to complete board . layout file is not with me .  whats ur take on listed 3 quick tips ?  thanks.

Comment: Impossible to say anything for sure without additional information. EMI is a holistic problem; it cannot be addressed by looking at a couple components in isolation, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to test, measure, and isolate the problem. For example, if U1 is demodulating the RF, no amount of filtering after it will help.

Comment: At 470MHz, a 1/4 wavelength is somewhere between 10cm and 16cm. If there are any slots in the enclosure, that are around that length, those will act as slot antennas. Wires that pass through the enclosure are also possible receiving antennas. It's also possible (depending on how bad the transmitter) that the impactful energy might not necessarily be 470MHz, it could be a higher-frequency spurious emission (so smaller slots are antennas), or it could be intermodulation distortion product (IMD) from the radio interacting with another nearby oscillator or nonlinear element.

Comment: If the problem is that unwanted RF is entering the enclosure through a slot or a wire, the cure might involve adding finger shielding to bridge the gaps, and make the box more like an ideal Faraday cage. But if the problem is IMD or spurious emissions from a cheap radio, the cure involves locating the fault which may be outside the enclosure. And there could be more than one problem, emc can be an "onion" problem.

Comment: The zero ohm resistor connecting AGND and DGND makes me worried about your board layout.  Post the layout and lets see what you're working with.

Comment: @MarkU agreed . first will work on enclosure and look for slots , openings which can be shielded or closed .

Comment: @user1850479 . Layout is not accessible  to me but it looks like two big copper island are joined by thin zero ohm of package 0603. Right angle connections and T connections  seem to be present on the layout . which could form antenna at this high frequency .

Comment: @user_1818839  currently figuring out the low cost instruments to do the pre-compliance in house . low power RF signal generators ( specs : Pmax=100mW for 50 ohm load)  and sniffer probes might work for near field testing i guess .

Comment: I would be much more worried about that split ground plane.  Star ground can be a good idea, but routing around then up through vias to an 0603 (which will add at least ohms of impedance between your AGND and DGND at 470 MHz) makes very little sense to me.  Usually you either don't split the GND at all or split it with a direct connection in plane to keep impedance as low as possible and prevent large current loops.

Comment: @user1850479 Agreed . since layout cant be modified immediately while debugging , will it be a good idea to  put a ferrite bead on the place of zero ohm to give high impedenace for RF noise and refrain it from disturbing the GND vtg levels ?

Comment: I would not expect adding additional impedance to help. My suggestion above was that ideally you would have lower impedance, but you can't do that with the board you have. Try shielding, maybe the ground is ok as it is.